# Remove SMS limit on KItKat with root access

Tags: android

I am using KitKat and would like to try to increase SMS limit so I can send more messages at the same time.

I tried a couple of tools for older Android versions but it seems they changed something in KitKat so nothing works. Because of that I've decided to do it by myself programmatically.

[Here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/com/android/internal/telephony/SmsUsageMonitor.java#SmsUsageMonitor) I've found this:

```
public class SmsUsageMonitor {
  private static final String TAG = "SmsUsageMonitor";
  private static final boolean DBG = false;
  private static final boolean VDBG = false;
  private static final String SHORT_CODE_PATH = "/data/misc/sms/codes";

  // Default checking period for SMS sent without user permission.
  private static final int DEFAULT_SMS_CHECK_PERIOD = 60000;

  // Default number of SMS sent in checking period without user permission.
  private static final int DEFAULT_SMS_MAX_COUNT = 30;

  ....

}
```

Now I was wondering how can I change this to `DEFAULT_SMS_MAX_COUNT` to 100 or some other number. Is there a way? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Look for:

Code:
    sput-boolean v1, Lcom/android/mms/MmsConfig;->mEnablePickContactLimit:Z
Change the sput-boolean from v1 to v0

Step 2.

Look for:

Code:
.method public static setRecipientLimit(I)
Remove below:

Code:
sput p0, Lcom/android/mms/MmsConfig;->mRecipientLimit:I
Step 3.

Look for:

Code:
.method public static getRecipientLimit()I
Remove below:

Code:
sget v0, Lcom/android/mms/MmsConfig;->mRecipientLimit:I
Step 4.

Look for:

Code:
.method public static getEnablePickContactLimit()Z
Remove below:

Code:
sget-boolean v0, Lcom/android/mms/MmsConfig;->mEnablePickContactLimit:Z
Save and close this file.

Step 5.

Next, navigate to and open \com\android\mms\ui\ComposeMessageFragment.smali

Look for:

Code:
.method public static getPickContactLimit()I
This may be responsible for the 200 limit as well, since 0xc8 = 200. Removing this does nothing for the 200 limit. But changing this to a higher number may increase the limit even more. I haven't bothered to find out. Report back any findings.

Remove below:

Code:
 const/16 v0, 0xc8
Save and close this file.

Part two - Increasing SMS hour limit

Step 1.
Navigate and open \com\android\mms\util\RateController.smali

Look for:

Code:
.field private static final RATE_LIMIT:I = 0x64
This value is in hexadecimal format, so we see that 0x64 = 100. So, to increase this to 1000 simply change 0x64 to 0x3e8

Save and close this file.

Recompile your classes.dex and replace the one in your SecMms.apk.

Credits to: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2055947

Comment: Thank you. Looks good but I would like to be able to do it programmatically if possible.

Answer (score 1):

As those constants are declared inside the Framework classes, and more so they are `private static final`(And for good reason with  aim  to prevent malicious apps sending huge amounts of SMS to premium rate numbers), so this limits can be overridden by OEM (companies who make devices) either by changing the source code or using the secure settings `Settings.Secure.SMS_OUTGOING_CHECK_MAX_COUNT`.

For rooted device, you may want to alter it by following:

```
sqlite3 /data/data/com.android.providers.settings/databases/settings.db

sqlite> INSERT INTO gservices (name, value) VALUES
('sms_outgoing_check_max_count', 10000);
```

This should set the upper limit to 10000.

Comment: Thank you. How can I do it programmatically inside my app? I tried to open that `settings.db` with a couple of tools but unsuccessfully. I would like to be able to do it programmatically.

Comment: There is no public API to access it AFAIK! You may need to use "Java Reflection" technique to access/manipulate that `private static final` field. I never tried it myself, all even the answer that I mentioned we use it for testing purpose!